# Finding a specific term in a repeating sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f(x) = \frac1{1-x}$,
and define the function $f^r$ by

$$f^r(x):=\underbrace{f(f(f(...f(f}_{r\text{ times}}(x))))).$$

I am asked to find to find $f^{653} (56)$.
I know that there are only $3$ different values which $f^{653}$ could be: $-1/55$, $55/56$ or $56$. Using a really tedious method, I got that the $653$-th term is $56$. The method I used took me about $20$ minutes and I am wondering if there is a "shortcut" approach to a problem like this.

Comment: I helped you with the formatting, please make sure everything is ok.

Comment: You can look up "continued fractions"

Comment: Thanks, Ian for the formatting help. And thank you Angelo, I will look up continued fractions. Do you know if the 653-th term is indeed 56?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $f^{2}(x) = \frac{x-1}{x}$ and that $f^{3}(x) = x$. Then reduce 653 mod 3. This gives $(653)\equiv 2 ~mod ~3$, so $f^{653}(x) =f^{2}(x)$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you, your explanation was perfect.

Comment: You are welcome.